# Can I use Huawei Mobile Services (HMS) for push notifications on non-Huawei devices?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, mdm

dear Stack Overflow community! I have an Android MDM agent that deploys a work profile on devices and needs to receive push notifications. My goal is to use Huawei Mobile Services (HMS) for push notifications.

I have a few questions:

```
Can I use HMS for push notifications on devices that are not Huawei devices? I plan to install HMS Core in the device profile if it is not Huawei.

Will push notifications work after installing HMS Core on non-Huawei devices?

Are there any limitations or considerations I should be aware of when using HMS for push notifications on various devices?
```

I would be grateful for any advice, experiences, and recommendations on this matter. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I haven't tried anything yet. Trying to research before :)